# how to confirm if the object was deleted in rails-for-API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rails-api

I created a destroy method and now I wanted to know how I can test and render if the object manages to be removed or not.

```
 def destroy
  if @syllabus.destroy
    render :no_content
  else 
  end
end
```

Comment: _test_ like you want to write a test for that controller method? Or _test and render_ like you want to check if the record was really deleted and then render some page to the user? Why do you think the `destroy` could fail?

Comment: actually i don't know how to do a destroy method in Rails-for-API. I don't know if the method I created is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails),
after following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#installation) on the gem repository you can generate a testing file with:

`bundle exec rails generate rspec:controller my_controller`

this would generate a file like the following:

```rb
# spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyControllerController, type: :controller do
# your code goes here...
end
```

then you can add a test example like this one:

```rb
# spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyControllerController, type: :controller do
  #replace attr1 and attr2 with your own attributes
  let(:syllabus) { Syllabus.create(attr1: 'foo', attr2: 'bar') } 

  it 'removes syllabus from table' do
    expect { delete :destroy, id: syllabus.id }.to change { Syllabus.count }.by(-1)
  end
end
```

** *the code above is not test and it was made just as a guide* **

for you destroy action method it's ok but, you could improve it a bit if you leave it like:

```rb
  def destroy
    @syllabus.destroy
  end
```

this is because your if/else condition is not doing much on the method and rails by default should respond with a `204 no content`